# Setting default Post header image in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I modify a Wordpress theme to auto-populate the header image of a Post if one hasn't been set manually? I'm a complete newbie when it comes to PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using get_post_meta() function you can achieve this functionality. You
>   can pass post id in first parameter , you can use custom_field_name in
>   second. And check like below code that it's available in database or
>   not.

Try this code.

```
<?php

    if(is_single() & !is_home()) 
    {
      $myfield = 'custom_field_name'; // Change this to the name of the custom field you use..
      $postimage = get_post_meta($post->ID, $myfield, true);
          if($postimage) 
          { 
                // If the field has a value.. set image path using value...
          } 
          elseif(!$postimage) 
          { 
                // If no value than set Default image path..
          }
    }
?>
```